# Sharepoint. The collection has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I trying to make simple sharepoint app on javascript.
I create list, named "test" and add some records where.
After starting my app i get error: "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested".
It raised in success function.
Here is code:

```
'use strict';

var web;
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
var collListItem;

function sharePointReady() {
    hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')
        );
    appweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl')
        );

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + '/_layouts/15/';

    $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js', function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js', function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', printAllListNamesFromHostWeb).fail(function () { alert("fail") });
        }).fail(function () { alert("fail") });
    }).fail(function () { alert("fail") });
    //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(printAllListNamesFromHostWeb, "SP.js");
    //printAllListNamesFromHostWeb();
}

function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == param) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}

function printAllListNamesFromHostWeb() {
    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;

    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

    web = appContextSite.get_web();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("testList");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, Title)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        //Function.createDelegate(this, success),
        //Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
        success, errorHandler
    );
}
function success(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
    }
    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
function errorHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('Fail: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
sharePointReady();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();`

above line in success function may be causing this issue.

You have declared `collListItem` variable in `printAllListNamesFromHostWeb` function. So it will not available/will be undefined in `success` function.

What you need to do is declare `collListItem` variable global (i.e. outside of your `printAllListNamesFromHostWeb` function where you have declared `appweburl,hostweburl,web` variables) and your code will work fine.

Comment: I move var declaration to top, but it not solve problem :(
I get same error.

Comment: Can you check in your console for which line of code you are getting this error.....

Comment: Error is same. Here is screenshot [https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziU9xeNGr_ced7fgw](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziU9xeNGr_ced7fgw). In english it "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested".

Comment: You have not closed `}` bracket for function `printAllListNamesFromHostWeb` after the line `context.executeQueryAsync`. Make this change and try again.

Comment: Nope :( still same error. Updated code in question. [https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziVMZCpVoJFCaDxGE](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziVMZCpVoJFCaDxGE)
[https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziVJlm7ruaUOQHVtl](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhQQocmm7pjziVJlm7ruaUOQHVtl)